# Получить индекс массива с найденым значением php

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу получить индекс массива найденного значения с ключом.

```
$array = [
  {
   "page_id" => 1
  },
  {
   "page_id" => 2
  },
];
echo array_search(["page_id" => "2"], $array, true);
```

Comment: `array_search(2, array_column($array, 'page_id'), true)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский большое спасибо